How to setup azure container instance to log to analytics workspace with terraform
I have a fairly vanilla docker image that is deployed to Azure via Azure container instance. It is set up with terraform and all of that seems to work as expected. However, I would like to get the container logs (i.e. stdout from the app) to appear in a log analytis workspace (also set up via terraform). I expected just adding the diganostics section as I have done below would be enough, but I can't find anything in the log analytics workspace even after waiting a while (to make sure that the logs have time to be ingested into log analytics). Is there some step I am missing?
One snag I did hit upon was that if I set the log_type to ContainerInstanceLogs the
deployment would fail (complaining that it didn't support metadata even though I didn't provide any). However, omitting that optional attribute in the log_analytics section everything deploys fine. Still it would be nice to actually get the logs into the workspace so they are more easily searchable!
resource "azurerm_container_group" "webapp" {
  count = length(local.names)
  name  = local.names[count.index]

  location            = azurerm_resource_group.rg.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.rg.name

  depends_on = [
    azurerm_container_group.init,
    azurerm_key_vault_access_policy.app_cg,
    azurerm_role_assignment.servicebus_owner,
  ]

  ip_address_type = "Private"
  os_type         = "Linux"

  diagnostics {
    log_analytics {
      workspace_id  = var.log_analytics_workspace_id
      workspace_key = var.log_analytics_workspace_key
    }
  }

  container {
    name   = "webapp"
    image  = "${var.registry_server}/app:${var.app_tag}" 
    cpu    = "0.25"
    memory = "0.5"

    ports {
      port     = 8080
      protocol = "TCP"
    }

    environment_variables = {
      "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT"         = "Production"
      "AZURE_KEY_VAULT_URL"            = var.keyvault_uri
      "AZURE_STORAGE_ACCOUNT_ENDPOINT" = var.storage_account_endpoint
      "ASPNETCORE_URLS"                = "http://+:8080"
      "AZURE_CLIENT_ID"                = azurerm_user_assigned_identity.container_group_identity.client_id
    }
  }

  image_registry_credential {
    server                    = var.registry_server
    user_assigned_identity_id = var.registry_identity_id
  }

  subnet_ids = [var.public_subnet_id]

  identity {
    type         = "UserAssigned"
    identity_ids = [azurerm_user_assigned_identity.container_group_identity.id, var.registry_identity_id]
  }

  tags = {
    "environment" = var.environment
  }
}


Try including the log_type as ContainerInstanceLogs in the log_analytics section and confirm that your Log Analytics workspace is configured to accept logs from the container instances @EmilL

@VinayB Thanks! I managed to figure out that the issue was a missing private link that the containers could use to send their logs to the workspace. I had set up the workspace to not ingest stuff over the public internet (good from a security point of view)!

Please feel free to post the solution it may help the community people who might face similar issue @EmilL


Azure container instance to log to analytics workspace with terraform

Hello Emil L, seems like you already found a solution to your problem.
The input you mentioned is on point as missing private link is preventing the Azure Container Instance (ACI) from sending logs to the Log Analytics workspace. when we performing ACI specially when your workspace is configured to not ingest data over the public internet its always better to maintain the connection between container and workspace.
I tried a demo configuration which helps in achieving this requirement for the community people who might come across such similar cases. Please feel free to add any points / your inputs to this if required.
Configuration:
resource "azurerm_monitor_private_link_scope" "monitor_pls" {
  name                = "vksb-monitor-private-link-scope"
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.rg.name
}

resource "azurerm_private_endpoint" "monitor_pe" {
  name                = "monitor-private-endpoint"
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.rg.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.rg.name
  subnet_id           = azurerm_subnet.monitor_subnet.id

  private_service_connection {
    name                           = "monitor-connection"
    private_connection_resource_id = azurerm_monitor_private_link_scope.monitor_pls.id
    is_manual_connection           = false
    subresource_names              = ["azuremonitor"]
  }
}

resource "azurerm_user_assigned_identity" "container_group_identity" {
  name                = "vksb-container-group-identity"
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.rg.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.rg.name
}


resource "azurerm_container_group" "webapp" {
  count = length(local.container_group_names)
  name  = local.container_group_names[count.index]

  location            = azurerm_resource_group.rg.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.rg.name

  ip_address_type = "Private"
  os_type         = "Linux"

  diagnostics {
    log_analytics {
      workspace_id  = azurerm_log_analytics_workspace.log_analytics.workspace_id
      workspace_key = azurerm_log_analytics_workspace.log_analytics.primary_shared_key
    }
  }

  container {
    name   = local.container_group_names[count.index]
    image  = "${var.registry_server}/app:${var.app_tag}"
    cpu    = "0.25"
    memory = "0.5"

    ports {
      port     = 8080
      protocol = "TCP"
    }

    environment_variables = {
      "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT" = "Production"
    }
  }

  identity {
    type = "UserAssigned"
    identity_ids = [
      azurerm_user_assigned_identity.container_group_identity.id
    ]
  }

  subnet_ids = [azurerm_subnet.aci_subnet.id]

  depends_on = [
    azurerm_log_analytics_workspace.log_analytics,
    azurerm_monitor_private_link_scope.monitor_pls,
    azurerm_private_endpoint.monitor_pe,
    azurerm_user_assigned_identity.container_group_identity
  ]
}

Deployment:


Refer:
azurerm_container_group | Resources | hashicorp/azurerm | Terraform | Terraform Registry
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/logs/private-link-security
